# About create tables in migration with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to start migration database code. please tell me briefly with code?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Creating the migration files or running them?

Comment: This question is rather vague... the best I could do is point to the rails guide on migrations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 1):

To create database

```
rake db:create
```

To run migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```

Some useful information

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations